# Vertically align item inside floating DIV that is inside LI

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, susy

I have list that has div's inside it

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="date">today</div>
        <div class="desc">lorem ipsum</div>
        <div class="action">
            <p>
                <a class="button">X</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>....</li>
    <li>....</li>
</ul>
```

How can I vertically align that a.button inside  div.action?

CSS for that list is generated by using Susy and the CSS looks something like this:

```
ul {
  list-style: none outside none;
}
li {
  margin-left: 12.766%;
  margin-right: 12.766%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  display: block;
}
li:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.date {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2.12766%;
  width: 10.6383%;
}
.desc {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2.12766%;
  width: 74.4681%;
}

.action {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 10.6383%;
}
```

I do not know the LI height because the "desc" text can be any length.

Here is the code at codepen.io -> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CFhos

Comment: Anything `float`ed will automatically rise to the top of its containing block. You'll have to use a different method of aligning the button on the right if you want to have it vertically centered.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can align just about anything - even floated elements...

Just add the following rules to the `li`:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center; /*align vertical */
```

**[Updated CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/zKtkn)**

Answer (score 1):

You can style the button to accomplish it like this:

```
.button{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Example here: **http://jsfiddle.net/4amdxtq8/**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without floating:

```
ul {
  list-style: none outside none;
}
li {
  display: table;
  margin-left: 12.766%;
  margin-right: 12.766%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
p {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.date {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 2.12766%;
  width: 10.6383%;
}
.desc {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 2.12766%;
  width: 74.4681%;
}

.action {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 10.6383%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yxhkA